# ¿Cómo pasar en unico parametro uno cualquiera de estos componentes; JButton, JTextField o JPasswordField?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero hacer un método que reciba por parametro un componente, sea JButton, JTextField o JPasswordField, dentro del método distinguir que componente ha recibido para tomar acción en función de este.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos, Pablo.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un método similar a este:

```
public void tuMetodo(Object componente) {
    if(componente instanceof JButton) {
        // Se trata de un JButton
    } else if(componente instanceof JPasswordField) {
        // Se trata de un JPasswordField
    } else if(componente instanceof JTextField) {
        // Se trata de un JTextField
    }
}
```

Solamente asegúrate que `JPasswordField` sea comprobado **antes** en el `if` del `JTextField`, porque básicamente un `JPasswordField` proviene de un `JTextField`, entonces si verificas primero el `JTextField`, el `JPasswordField` pasará por ahí y no por donde debería.

Ahora bien, el único detalle es que ese parámetro aceptará cualquier tipo de objeto, y no únicamente componentes, si lo que deseas es que únicamente se acepten componentes podrías cambiar de `Object` a `JComponent` (puesto que en su mayoría los componentes de Java provienen de un `JComponent`).

Comment: Hola C. Rodriguez, 
Gracias por la respuesta. Exactamente es lo que quiero lograr.
El código arroja el siguiente error; Syntax error on token "instanceOf", instanceof expected.

Comment: Saludos, Pablo. Sí, disculpa, fue un error mío. No es `instanceOf`, sino `instanceof`. Ya corregí la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero te de una Idea en C# lo realizo de la Siguiente Manera

```
public void llenarGrid(DataGridView grid, datatable datos)
{
  // Codigo ...
}
```

y lo llamo de la Siguiente Manera

```
llenarGrid(nombre_de_mi_componente, datos);
```

Supongo que para Java sera algo parecido

```
public void sendControl(JTextField control)
{
   //tu Codigo 
}
```